# SQLSRV bind param thats in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sqlsrv

I'm trying to convert this mysql code to work using sqlsrv

```
$planeId = $_GET["pid"];

$conn = OpenCon();

$sql = "SELECT id, pid, fullname, tat, date, engine1, engine2, engine3, engine4 FROM oil WHERE pid = ? order by date desc";
$stmnt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmnt->bind_param("s", $planeId);
$stmnt->bind_result($id, $pid, $fullname, $tat, $date, $engine1, $engine2, $engine3, $engine4);
$stmnt->execute();
$theRows = Array();
while ( $stmnt->fetch() )
{
    $aRow['id'] = "$id";
    $aRow['pid'] = "$pid";
    $aRow['fullname'] = $fullname;
    $aRow['tat'] = $tat;
    $aRow['date'] = $date;
    $aRow['engine1'] = $engine1;
    $aRow['engine2'] = $engine2;
    $aRow['engine3'] = $engine3;
    $aRow['engine4'] = $engine4;

    $theRows[] = $aRow;
}

$stmnt->close();

echo json_encode($theRows);

CloseCon($conn);
```

This I what I've done so far but I'm missing the bind-param function not sure how to implement that. Because the output keeps coming out like this

```
[{"id":"","pid":"","fullname":null,"tat":null,"date":null,"engine1":null,"engine2":null,"engine3":null,"engine4":null}]
```

Even though I know there's an entry in Microsoft DB

```
$planeId = $_GET["pid"];
$theRows = Array();
$conn = OpenCon();

$query = "SELECT id, pid, fullname, tat, date, engine1, engine2, engine3, engine4 FROM oil WHERE pid = ? order by date desc";

//$stmnt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmnt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $query, array(&$planeId));

if (sqlsrv_execute($stmnt) === false){
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
else{
    while ( sqlsrv_fetch($stmnt) )
    {
        $aRow['id'] = "$id";
        $aRow['pid'] = "$pid";
        $aRow['fullname'] = $fullname;
        $aRow['tat'] = $tat;
        $aRow['date'] = $date;
        $aRow['engine1'] = $engine1;
        $aRow['engine2'] = $engine2;
        $aRow['engine3'] = $engine3;
        $aRow['engine4'] = $engine4;

        $theRows[] = $aRow;
    }
    echo json_encode($theRows);
}
CloseCon($conn);
```

Comment: Just use PDO instead.

Comment: im just missing the bind result part and i think we should be good, dont know much about PDO

Comment: PDO is the general API for talking to a database. It has many drivers and it is much better than mysqli or sqlsrv. It would be so much easier if you used it.

Comment: See an example here how to fetch data using sqlsrv https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php

Comment: ya i already looked at that document, i dont know how to assign the value of ID from the sql to the php

Comment: Simple `$record = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmnt); $id = $record['id'];`

Comment: Thought of doing something like this too

$id = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmnt, 0);
$aRow['id'] = "$id";

Comment: Thank you @Dharman ok i got it to work, it worked using both methods, but my date field is coming up weird: any idea how i can fix that, right now its set to use date as type and default of current timestamp in my microsoft DB.
[{"id":"1","pid":"1","fullname":"Billy bob","tat":"1.00","date":{"date":"2020-06-27 13:54:34.307000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"engine1":"1.00","engine2":".00","engine3":".00","engine4":".00"}]

Comment: What do you mean weird?

Comment: It's coming out like this
`"date":{"date":"2020-06-27 13:54:34.307000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}`
I would like it like this:
`"date":"2020-06-27 13:54:34.307000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"`

Basically i want the subfield to output

Comment: It's exactly the same

Comment: "date":{"date": to "date":

Comment: Ok, that's what you meant. Yeah, this is DateTime object. It's how you operate on Dates in PHP. Probably this answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29003881/1839439 See here for explanation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-retrieve-date-and-time-type-as-strings-using-the-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: An [asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61350489/data-type-differences-between-php-sqlsrv-driver-and-pdo-driver/61352482#61352482) about retrieving date/time values using PHP Driver for SQL Server.